# Can 2 controller can load the same view page?

Tags: codeigniter

**Controller 1:**

```
function view($ev_id){                 
     $this->load->model('usermodel');

     $data = $this->usermodel->act_join($ev_id);            
     //print_r($total);
     foreach($data->result_array() as $row){
        $ev_name = $row['ev_name']; 
        $image = $row['ev_image'];
        $start = $row['start'];
        $end = $row['end'];
        $desc = $row['ev_desc'];
        $ev_id  = $row['ev_id'];
        $id= $row['id'];
      }

      $data = array( 'ev_name' =>  $ev_name,
                      'ev_image' => $image,
                      'start' => $start,
                      'end' =>  $end,
                      'ev_desc' => $desc,
                      'ev_id' => $ev_id,
                      'id'  => $id                          
                   );  
       $this->load->view('view_event',$data);
}
```

how to pass multiple values to the view

**Controller 2:**

```
function check() {

     $this->load->model('usermodel');
     $query = $this->usermodel->join($ev_id);
     print_r($query)
     $this->load->view('view_event',$query);
}
```

> Can 2 controller can load the same view page

Comment: Yes this can be possible. Different controller can load same view page.

Comment: i need 2 diff fun in same controller can have same view page

Comment: Ya sure it can be possible.

Comment: but it not working properly...

Answer (score 0):

your are making a major misktake
when to pass data to a view you need to make array
for e.g
you have array

```
$data['test']= array( 'ev_name' =>  $ev_name,
                      'ev_image' => $image,
                      'start' => $start,
                      'end' =>  $end,
                      'ev_desc' => $desc,
                      'ev_id' => $ev_id,
                      'id'  => $id                          
                   );
  $this->load->view('view_event',$data);
```

now in view all the values of array can be get

```
<?php echo $test ;?>
```

try it and bingo